# Are there any tilling desktop environments (not window managers)

Tags: desktop-environments, tiling

I recently tried i3 recently (switching from gnome) and I liked the controls and window management but hated how nothing that doesn't involve window management is included and I have to set up my own lockscreen, volume controls, suspend, and all the other goodies that come with a DE.

All the solutions to these problems online just involve manually changing configs to include every single thing you want to do.

Is there any tiling window system which comes with the whole lot and the kitchen sink?

Comment: Install XFCE or LXDE and run i3 instead of whatever WM they include?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a desktop environment for that. You can just `--replace` the existing WM of the desktop environment currently in use but some DEs are a bit picky.

XFCE works perfectly in this case, install XFCE and then install the WM of your choice for instance `compiz` and then just add a startup script with one command: `compiz --replace` (if you were running compiz).

If `compiz` is not the one you want to use then look through the `--help` menu of the chosen WM to find the equivalent flag for `--replace`.

Before adding a start-up script, test it from a terminal. Here are some commands that you can use with XUbuntu:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install compiz-core
compiz --replace
```

If that works, create a new ASCII file and call it **replace-wm** with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
compiz --replace
```

Then make the file executable:

```
chmod u+x replace-wm
```

Then using XFCE's Session and Startup settings, add the path of **replace-wm** as a startup script.